# Installable embedding allowing for OTF font file

Tags: html, css, fonts

We have a site with otf font files.
Everything works fine except how site looks in IE 11.
After investigation we have found a reason:

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
```

I have checked Installable embedding allowance for otf files on Windows and there is font embeddability is set as Installable.

Also I use [tool](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/) that makes font file Installable.  But the tool breaks otf file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If IE complains about the permission bit, it's actually a good bet the permission bit *isn't* set to installable. Using a hack-tool to change it to permissible is pretty much the opposite of a good idea, because if a font foundry bothered to set the installability bit, good bet it's against their license for you to break the font open AND then install it. Instead, get a proper license for the font. Which font is this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use .woff file extension for fonts instead .otf.
First, I have tried to covert .otf file to .woff format using one of free online tools for the conversion. But it broke the license.
So we decided to ask .woff files from the designer.